# Java + MongoDB: Updating multiple fields in a document

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to update at once multiple fields in a single MongoDB document, but only one field is updated.
I have a collection **user**, in which users are uniquely defined by a **customer_user_id**. I want to update a certain user's **birth_year** and **country** fields.

This is what I am doing:

```
// Define the search query:
DBCollection col = md.getDb().getCollection("user");
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("customer_user_id", customer_user_id);

// Define the update query:
BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
updateQuery.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("birth_year", birth_year);
updateQuery.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("country", country);

log.info("Update query: " + updateQuery);
col.update(searchQuery, updateQuery);
```

Unfortunately, only the **country** field is updated, and the logged updateQuery looks like this:

> Update query: { "$set" : { "country" : "Austria"}}

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I cannot verify that but maybe you should try:

```
BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject();
updateFields.append("birth_year", birth_year);
updateFields.append("country", country);
BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject();
setQuery.append("$set", updateFields);
col.update(searchQuery, setQuery);
```

or this is pretty the same I think:

```
updateQuery.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("country",country).append("birth_year", birth_year));
```

Comment: @wawek, I'm trying your approach and none of the document's field is not updated. I'm querying the documents by `_id`, which exist and trying to push an update of the specific fields but nothing happens.
Code: `BasicDBObject searchQry = new BasicDBObject("_id", epID);
BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject();
updateFields.append("isExpired", true);
updateFields.append("fetchStatus", FetchStatus.FETCHED.getID());
BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject();
setQuery.append("$set", updateFields);
UpdateResult updRes = dbC_Episodes.updateOne(searchQry, setQuery);`

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, there are convenience methods in `com.mongodb.client.model.Updates` to do this:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("db").getCollection("user");

collection.updateMany(
    Filters.eq("customer_user_id", customer_user_id),
    Updates.combine(
        Updates.set("birth_year", birth_year),
        Updates.set("country", country)
    ));
```

Underlying this will create a Bson query with `$set` as well, but using convenience methods keeps your code more clear and readable.

Comment: According to docs, `updateMany` updates all documents, not multiple fields in a single MongoDB document.

Comment: Hi @Half_Duplex, can you justify your statement by giving proper example. Also can you share the MongoDB doc link which contains this statement. Thanks

Comment: Does `combine` create an aggregation pipeline or a normal / traditional update (i.e. a single `set` statement?

Answer (score 8):

For MongoDB 3.4 you can use

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(nameOfCollection);
Bson filter = new Document("SearchKey", Value);   
Bson newValue = new Document("UpdateKey1", "Value1").append("UpdateKey2", "Value2")....;      
Bson updateOperationDocument = new Document("$set", newValue);
collection.updateMany(filter, updateOperationDocument);
```

Comment: Yeah.. this is the new way.

Comment: The new way is not using `new Document("$set", new Document("fieldA", "valueA"))`.  The new way is to use `com.mongodb.client.model.Updates` as answered by @pakat

Answer (score 1):

A variation on answer by @pakat...

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("db").getCollection("user");

List<Bson> updatePredicates = new ArrayList<Bson>();
Bson predicateBirthYear = set("birth_year", birth_year);
Bson predicateCountry = set("country", country);

updatePredicates.add(predicateBirthYear);
updatePredicates.add(predicateCountry);

collection.updateMany(Filters.eq("customer_user_id", customer_user_id), Updates.combine(updatePredicates));
```